# Select a specific child node based on tag using XPath or lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, children

I have an XML file similar to this. And I'd like to select a child node based on its tag

```
<list>
  <age>
    <John>18</John>
    <Tom>22</Tom>
    <Samer>19</Samer>
    <Mark>21</Mark>
  </age>
</list>
```

Is there a way to select "Tom node" for example, starting from the "age node"?

I tried something like that `ageNode.xpath("/Tom")` but it's not working. The `ageNode.getchildren()[1]` works, but the thing is order is different every time. ***So I can only depend on tag NOT on order***.

I'm using python 2.7 and lxml package.

Comment: Try `ageNode.xpath("Tom")`

Comment: And it's that simple. Thanks, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` at the beginning of XPath always reference the root node. To do a relative XPath, you need to either add a `.` or remove `/` completely, as mentioned in the comment :

```
ageNode.xpath("./Tom")
ageNode.xpath("Tom")
```